# Given two orthogonal vectors $a$ and $b$, is $\|a\|_1 \leq 2\|a+b\|_1$?

Tags: vector-spaces, normed-spaces

Given two vectors $a$ and $b$ with $a^Tb = 0$ and with dimensions $n \ge 2$, I want to prove the bound $\|a\|_1 \leq 2\|a+b\|_1$. The triangle inequality gives us $\|a\|_1 \leq \|a+b\|_1 + \|b\|_1$ and for $\|b\|_1 \leq \|a+b\|_1$ the bound obviously holds. For the L2 norm the bound $\|a\|_2 \leq \|a+b\|_2$ also obviously holds due to Pythagoras.

I suspect that $\|a+b\|_1$ cannot be much smaller than $\|b\|_1$, especially given that $\|a+b\|_2 > \|b\|_2$. In particular it seems $\|a+b\|_1 \ge {1\over2}\|b\|_1$. Note that there are cases where $\|a+b\|_1 < \|b\|_1$:

```
octave:201> aa1', bb1', norm(aa1+bb1,1)/norm(bb1,1)
ans =

   0.5944   0.2709  -0.5054   0.3410  -0.4527

ans =

   1.1160  -0.1212   0.5414  -0.3573   0.5192

ans = 0.7453
```

I can see two extreme cases: $a$ and $b$ being axis aligned, or either being maximally not-axis-aligned (all 1's or -1's times a constant).

When $a = [1, 0, 0, \dots 0]$ and $b = [0, r, 0, \dots , 0]$ and $r > 0$ then $\|a\|_1 = 1$, $\|b\|_1 = r$ and $\|a+b\|_1 = 1+r$ and the inequality holds.

When $a = [1, 1, \dots , 1]$ and $b = [r, \dots , r, -r, \dots , -r]$ with equal amounts of positive and negative $r$'s then $\|a\|_1 = n$, $\|b\|_1 = nr$ and for $0 < r \leq 1$ then $\|a+b\|_1 = n$ and the inequality holds. For $r > 1$ then $\|a+b\|_1 = nr$ and the inequality also holds.

When $a = [1, -1, 0, \dots , 0]$ and $b = [r, \dots , r]$ then $\|a\|_1 = 2$, $\|b\|_1 = nr$ and if $0 < r \le 1$ then $\|a+b\|_1 = 2 + (n-2)r = 2 + nr - 2r \ge nr$ and the inequality holds. For $r > 1$ then $\|a+b\|_1 = 1+r + (r-1) + (n-2)r = 2r + nr -2r = nr$ and again the inequality holds.

I cannot see any more extreme cases. In particular the ratio between the ratios between the L1 and L2 norms also seems to be bounded:

```
octave:205> aaa', bbb', (norm(aaa+bbb,1)/norm(bbb,1))/(norm(aaa+bbb,2)/norm(bbb,2))
ans =

   0.582462   0.043722   0.881977   0.778945   0.904567

ans =

  -2.2616e-02   9.0037e-01  -4.9924e-02   4.5515e-03   1.5801e-02

ans = 2.0024
```

In dimensions greater than 10 or so I cannot find any vectors that have a ratio greater than 2.
The above also only seems to work when $\|b\|_1 < \|a+b\|_1$ (in which case the inequality I'm after holds anyway) and only up do 7 or so dimensions. When $\|b\|_1 > \|a+b\|_1$ I cannot find any such vectors.

I feel like there's a simple proof for all this, possible having to do either with the triangle inequality or the homogeniety of norms or possibly involving Hölder's inequality..

Update: I have some partial results:

- $\|a\|_1 \leq 2\|a+b\|_1 + 2\|{1\over2}a+b\|_1$
- $\|a\|_1 \leq 2\|a+b\|_1 + 2\|a+{1\over2}b\|_1$
- $\|a\|_1 \leq \|a+b\|_1 + \|{1\over2}a+b\|_1 + \|a+{1\over2}b\|_1$
- $\|a\|_1 \leq \|a+b\|_1 + 2\|a+{1\over2}b\|_1$
- $\|a\|_1 \nleq \|a+b\|_1 + 2\|{1\over2}a+b\|_1$

These identities hold elementwise and therefore they hold for the sums as well because of the convexity of the $p$-norms when $p \geq 1$.

Also, for arbitrary $a$ and $b$ the inequality $\|a+b\|_1 \ge {1\over2}\|b\|_1$ does not hold, for example $a = 1$, $b = -1$ gives $|1-1| < 0.5|-1|$. But this might not be the case for orthogonal $a$ and $b$.

Update 2: The inequality holds for 5 dimensions when $a$ is all ones by the following lp_solve program having no solution:

```
min: 0;
-inf <= b1;
-inf <= b2;
-inf <= b3;
-inf <= b4;
-inf <= b5;
b1 + b2 + b3 + b4 + b5 = 0;
s1 = 1 + b1;
s2 = 1 + b2;
s3 = 1 + b3;
s4 = 1 + b4;
s5 = 1 + b5;
s1 <= p1; -s1 <= p1;
s2 <= p2; -s2 <= p2;
s3 <= p3; -s3 <= p3;
s4 <= p4; -s4 <= p4;
s5 <= p5; -s5 <= p5;
5 >= 2 p1 + 2 p2 + 2 p3 + 2 p4 + 2 p5;
```

Removing the orthogonality constraint `b1 + b2 + b3 + b4 + b5 = 0;` leads to a feasible solution, so orthogonality definitely plays a part.

Comment: Oh yeah, the title makes it seem like I want $||a+b||_1/||b||_1$ bounded from above, but what I really want is $||b||_1/||a+b||_1 \leq C$ so that I can bound $||a||_1$ in terms of $||a+b||_1$. Updating.

Comment: I already know that $||b||_1 \leq \sqrt{n}||a+b||_1$ which follows from Hölder and Cauchy-Schwartz. I mention in the first paragraph that I want a bound tighter than that, and it seems that $||b||_1 \leq C||a+b||_1$ for orthogonal $a$ and $b$ and some $1 \leq C \leq 2$ but I can't prove it.

Comment: I have simply removed the statement about $\sqrt{n}$. Yes I know it applies for $C = 2$ but I am also curious if there is a smaller $C$ :)

Comment: I meant to say if $C < 2$ applies then obviously $C = 2$ also applies. Sorry about, I was in a rush.

Comment: probabily the best hope is formulate it as an LP with absolute values and reformulate it to a solvable one somehow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a counterexample: take $a = (1, 1/\sqrt{d}, 1/\sqrt{d},\dots)$ of length $d+1$. Take $b= (1, -1/\sqrt{d}, -1/\sqrt{d}, \dots).$ We have $\langle a,b\rangle = 1 - d \cdot 1/d = 0$, $\|a+b\|_1 = 2$, but $\|a\|_1 = 1 + \sqrt{d},$ and for large $d$ this is much bigger than $4$.

Below I'll discuss how I arrived at this, which basically studies how small we can make $\|a+b\|_1$.

---

Let $f(b;a) := \|a + b\|_1$. Then notice that for given $a$, $$ \min_b \|a+b\|_1 : \langle a,b\rangle = 0$$ is a convex program. We can thus analyse the first order conditions and obtain some structural properties of the $b$ that minimises this. Without loss of generality, we shall assume that $a_1 > a_2 > \dots > a_n > 0$ (the ordering and signs are trivial, we can assume strict inequality by adding an arbitrarily small perturbation.

Construct the Lagrangian $$ \mathcal{L}_a(b;\lambda) = \|a+b\|_1 + \lambda \langle a,b\rangle.$$ For a fixed $a,\lambda,$ the subgradient of $\mathcal{L}_a$ in $b$ is the set $$ \partial\mathcal{L}_a(b;\lambda) = \{v: \textrm{if } a_i + b_i > 0, v_i = 1 + \lambda a_i, \textrm{if } a_i + b_i < 0, v_i =- 1 + \lambda a_i,\\ \textrm{else } v_i \in [-1 + \lambda a_i , 1 + \lambda a_i] \}.$$

Of course the first order condition demands that $0$ must be in the subgradient set above.

Now, notice that if for some $i, a_i + b_i > 0 \implies \lambda = -1/a_i,$ then for any $j$ such that $a_j > a_i,$ we have $1 + \lambda a_j < 0$. Further, for all $j$ such that $a_j < a_i,$ we have $1 + \lambda a_j = 1-a_j/a_i > 0,$ and $-1 + \lambda a_j = -1 -a_j/a_i < 0.$ This means that if there is a particular coordinate $i^*$ such that $a_{i^*} + b_{i^*} > 0,$ then for all other corrdinates $i$ such that $a_i \neq a_{i^*},$ it must hold that $b_i = -a_i$.

But the same idea also holds if there is some coordinate such that $a_i + b_i < 0.$ Indeed, in this case we have $\lambda = 1/a_i,$ and so if $a_j > a_i,$ then $-1 + a_j/a_i > 0,$ while if $a_j < a_i,$ then $1 + a_j/a_i > 0$ and $-1 + a_j/a_i < 0$.

It follows that the optimal $b$ satisfies the following structure: pick a coordinate $i$. Set $b_j = -a_j$ for all $j \neq i,$ and set $b_i$ to meet the constraint on the inner product. For the choice of coordinate $i$, then, $$ b_i = -\frac{\sum_{j \neq i} a_j b_j }{a_i} = \frac{\sum_{j \neq i} a_j^2}{a_i} = \frac{\|a\|_2^2 - a_i^2}{a_i}.$$ With this structure, of course, the value of the objective $\|a+b\|_1$ is $$ \theta_i = \frac{\|a\|_2^2}{a_i}.$$ Minimising this of course requires that we choose the largest coordinate, and so we conclude that $$ \min_b \|a+b\|_1 : \langle a,b\rangle = 0 = \frac{\|a\|_2^2}{|a_1|}.$$ But note that $|a_1| = \|a\|_\infty$. So,your claim is equivalent to arguing that $$\|a\|_\infty \|a\|_1 \le 2 \|a\|_2^2.$$

But it's relatively straightforward to break this. Make the bulk of $a$ have a small repeated entry, because this is the case where $\|\cdot \|_1 \le \sqrt{n}\|\cdot\|_2$ is tight. Throw in a big entry so that $\|\cdot\|_\infty$ is comparable to $\|\cdot\|_2$, and we're done. The countexample I gave does exactly this.

---

In hindsight, maybe this should have been more obvious: one consequence of your conjecture is that for any orthogonal $a,b,$ $\|a\|_1 + \|b\|_1 \le 4\|a+b\|_1.$ This is spectacularly violated for $b = -a$. The orthogonality constraint is just one linear constraint, and we can sort of push $a,b$ into a pair of complementary subspaces to do this, but this leaves plenty of wiggle room to still make the inequality fail, especially in large dimensions.

Comment: I came to a very similar conclusion just now, including regarding $||a||_\infty$ and was very excited because a negative result is also a result :)

Using the same sign flipping on $a$ as you, it is further necessary that $-{2 \over 3}b_i < a_i < -2 b_i$ for sufficiently many negative $b_i$. This can be seen by plotting $2|a + b| - a$.